# Meaning of Youtube url ?v=some_code

Tags: url, youtube

What does the part *after* the `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` mean ?

Is it some *hashcode* or something?

Any idea how it's *calculated* ?

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `v` parameter is the Video ID. It seems that the process which produces this ID isn't widely published. Even the fact that it is 11 characters long isn't something that is set in stone and even the ID's of current video might change in the future.

You can read about it further [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54443/format-for-id-of-youtube-video).
 
There are two answers there. The first is giving a short answer stating that not much, if anything, is known about the IDs. The other answer is by someone trying to reverse engineer the video ID, explaining his process.